# Split alphanumeric column without delimiter pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas dataframe, where i need to split the column into multiple columns, the issue I am facing is there is no delimiter to the column value. Here is the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd   
data =   ['MSFT220121C00180000','MSFT220121C00185000','MSFT220121C00200000'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['contract']) 
df
```

output

```
    contract
0   MSFT220121C00180000
1   MSFT220121C00185000
2   MSFT220121C00200000
```

desired output

```
   ticker date  type series
0   MSFT 220121 C 00180000
1   MSFT 220121 C 00185000
2   MSFT 220121 C 00200000
```

I tried something with regex

```
r = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
 ('MSFT', '220121')
```

which didn't give me the desired result.

Comment: Wait in this case you must use pandas.Series.str.extract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`series.str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
m=df.contract.str.extractall('([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)').unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
m.columns=['ticker','date','type','series']
print(m)
```

Or:

```
import itertools
m=pd.DataFrame([[*itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)] 
               for i in df.contract.str.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)')],
               columns=['ticker','date','type','series'])
```

---

```
  ticker    date type    series
0   MSFT  220121    C  00180000
1   MSFT  220121    C  00185000
2   MSFT  220121    C  00200000
```

Comment: this looks like the correct solution, however when I apply this to my actual dataframe with lot of data, I am getting a 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: @Masterbuilder it happens when you have a duplicate index, which doesnot seem to be the case for your test dataframe on which my solution works fine.

Comment: agree, what would be the approach for duplicate index while unstack

Comment: @Masterbuilder can you try withh the second method i posted?

Comment: perfect! itertools is the way to go . Thank you very much.